# Proving an Inequality with the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: analysis

I've been trying to prove that $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} < \frac{x-y}3$ for all $x>y\ge3$. I've done the following work.

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be the function given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}.$ Note that f is continuous and differentiable on its domain and $f'(x) = \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$. Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in  (y,x)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}}{x-y} = \frac1{2\sqrt{c}}.$ I'm not sure where to go from here, since I can't see how $c > 3$ implies $\frac1{2\sqrt{c}} < \frac13$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3 < 2 \sqrt{c} \iff 9 < 4c \iff \frac{9}{4} < c$. $(c>0)$ Hence $c>3$ is sufficient for $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}<\frac{1}{3}$